# Splunk: mvzip two JSON Arrays

Tags: splunk-query

I am trying to find frequently used search filters from my application log using Splunk.

I have written a below query to extract a json from the log and store it in the search_filter variable

```
index="*" "Searching records" 
| rex field=_raw "(?P<search_filter>\{.*\})" 
| eval search_filter=replace(search_filter,"\\\\\"","\"")
```

The resulting json in the *search_filter* variable for one event looks like below

```
{
 "pageSize": 0,
 "offset": 0,
 "criteria":[
   {
     "field": "status",
     "operator": "equalsIgnoreCase",
     "values":["REPROCESS"]
  },
  {
    "field": "id",
    "operator": "equals",
    "values":["352353"]
  }]
}
```

Now I want to convert this json in the below format and then finally sort this array and list it in the table ordered by count.

```
[status##equalsIgnoreCase,id##equals]
```

I tried doing the below

```
index="*" "Searching records" 
| rex field=_raw "(?P<search_filter>\{.*\})" 
| eval search_filter=replace(search_filter,"\\\\\"","\"") 
| eval cfo=json_extract(search_filter, "criteria{}.field", "criteria{}.operator") 
| eval cf=json_extract(cfo,"{0}") 
| eval co=json_extract(cfo,"{1}") 
| eval cfos=mvzip(cf, co, "##")
```

The result in *cfos* variable is like below

```
["status","id"]##["equalsIgnoreCase","equals"]
```

I am not able to zip two JSON arrays or find anyway to do it.

Any suggestions on how to combine two JSON array and then sort it in my example or let me know if I can achieve this thing in a different manner.
Thank you.

Comment: I don't know what json_extract is but spath seems to work: `| spath input=search_filter | rename criteria{}.field as cf | rename criteria{}.operator as co | eval cfos=mvzip(cf,co,"##") | table cfos cf co`  That produces a mv fields with `status##equalsIgnoreCase` and `id##equals`

Comment: It's interesting.  I just found the splunk documentation for the json functions and none of them exist on my server except spath and makejson....